# Fetching models that are similar - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method inside my `Business` class:

```
def similar_businesses(n)
    Business.where(:category_id => category_id, :city_id => city_id).where("id NOT IN (?)",id).limit(n).order("RANDOM()")
end
```

It basically grabs `n` businesses that are in the same category and same city.

I was looking at a railscast that talks about using class methods instead of scopes, and tried to convert my code into:

```
def similar_businesses(n)
    where(:category_id => category_id, :city_id => city_id).where("id NOT IN (?)",id).limit(n).order("RANDOM()")
end
```

Notice `Business` is not there anymore.

However, I am getting an error `undefined where method for ...`

I have just started rails, and I am also wondering if there is any difference between these two methods? And why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to use `similar_businesses` as a *class* method rather than *instance* method. The difference between the two is that you play class method for classes, such as Business and you apply instance method for something like `@business = Business.new`.

Try using

```
def self.similar_businesses(n)
  where(:category_id => category_id, :city_id => city_id).where("id NOT IN (?)",id).limit(n).order("RANDOM()")
end
```

Comment: Alright I understand that. Would one be more efficient than the other?

Comment: In the above case, there is no difference in efficiency because you are basically doing the same thing, the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the method as `def self.similar_businesses` to make it a class method.

Comment: I changed and now I am getting `undefined method 'similar_businesses' for #<Business:0x007fb4e2497458>`. How can I call the class method from an instance?

Comment: You can't (well you can by getting the class from the instance and calling it on that but you don't need to). Just call it like this: `Business.similar_businesses`.